# Remove duplicates from the below SQL query

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

#### SQL Table

```
id       component   price  manufactured
1         fx card   500     2011
2         ram       400     2010
3         case      400     2010
4         smps      500     2011
5         cord      200     2010
6         usb       200     2010
```

Expected output (Return components of same price and manufactured yr as distinct combinations):

```
component   component   price   manufactured
smps        fx card     500     2011
case        ram         400     2010
cord        usb         200     2010
```

#### Query tried

```
SELECT m1.[component]
  ,m2.[component]
  ,m1.[price]
  ,m1.[manufactured]
FROM [dbo].[Mfg] m1
inner join [dbo].[Mfg] m2
on m1.component != m2.component 
and m1.price = m2.price 
and m1.manufactured = m2.manufactured
```

Result from above query (wrong output though):

```
component   component   price   manufactured
smps        fx card     500    2011
case        ram         400    2010
cord        usb         200    2010
ram         case        400    2010
fx card     smps        500    2011
usb         cord        200    2010
```

Please help me eliminating the duplicate combos using the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if no pairs of components share the same name:

```
SELECT m1.[component]
      ,m2.[component]
      ,m1.[price]
      ,m1.[manufactured]
FROM [dbo].[Mfg] m1
JOIN [dbo].[Mfg] m2 ON m1.component > m2.component 
                   AND m1.price = m2.price 
                   AND m1.manufactured = m2.manufactured;
```

All I changed was to trade the inequality operator `!=` for a `greater than` operator. This way you get every pair once instead of twice.

To provide for the possibility of **identical names**:

```
JOIN [dbo].[Mfg] m2 ON m1.id > m2.id
                   AND m1.price = m2.price 
                   AND m1.manufactured = m2.manufactured;
```

I assume `id` is unique, so it can't go wrong.